# How to compile ffmpeg with x11grab? xlib missing

Tags: compiler-errors, ffmpeg, centos

I am compiling ffmpeg on centos 7.1 x64. The error message I got is

```
#### FFmpeg static build, by STVS SA ####
*** Building FFmpeg ***
ERROR: Xlib not found
```

config.log

```
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -I/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/include -I/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/include -static --static -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -pthread -I/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/include/opus -I/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/include -I/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/include -I/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/include -I/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/include -I/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/include -I/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/include -c -o /tmp/ffconf.eYdD6TBQ.o /tmp/ffconf.UnBT7bp1.c
gcc -L/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lm -L/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lm -static -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -o /tmp/ffconf.6gKhjd90 /tmp/ffconf.eYdD6TBQ.o -lxcb -lxvidcore -L/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lx264 -lpthread -lm -L/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lvpx -lm -L/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lvpx -lm -L/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lvpx -lm -L/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lvpx -lm -lvorbisenc -lvorbis -logg -ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -logg -L/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lrtmp -lz -lssl -lcrypto -L/home/shuman/github/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lopus -lmp3lame -lfaac -lm -lbz2 -lz -pthread -ldl -lXext
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxcb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: Xlib not found
```

but I have yum installed libxcb, what could be the reason for this?

edit:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep libxcb
libxcb-devel-1.11-4.el7.x86_64
libxcb-1.11-4.el7.i686
libxcb-1.11-4.el7.x86_64
compat-libxcb-1.9-1.el7.x86_64

$ locate xcb.h
/home/shuman/Downloads/buildroot/package/x11r7/libxcb/libxcb.hash
/usr/include/X11/Xlib-xcb.h
/usr/include/cairo/cairo-xcb.h
/usr/include/xcb/xcb.h

$ locate xcb.so
/home/shuman/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.10.11/libX11-xcb.so.1
/home/shuman/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.10.11/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
/usr/lib/libX11-xcb.so
/usr/lib/libX11-xcb.so.1
/usr/lib/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/libxcb.so.1
/usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
/usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so
/usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1
/usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib64/libxcb.so
/usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1
/usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
```

edit: it turns out that it's because I'm not using the correct configure commandline, after following this [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos#FFmpeg), it works now

```
CFLAGS="-I$TARGET_DIR/include" LDFLAGS="-L$TARGET_DIR/lib" ./configure --prefix=${OUTPUT_DIR:-$TARGET_DIR} --extra-cflags="-I$TARGET_DIR/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$TARGET_DIR/lib"  --pkg-config-flags="--static" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-librtmp
```

in which, $TARGET_DIR is where all the dependency libs installed, this is part of my static ffmpeg [build script](https://github.com/oglops/ffmpeg-static/tree/dev) ( with librtmp and libx265 and x11grab)

Comment: Try installing `libxcb-devel` (or whatever the appropriate development package for it is).

Comment: I checked it is already installed, but still can not find it.

Comment: The `libxcb-devel` package is installed? Not just the `libxcb` package? What does `rpm -q libxcb libxcb-devel` output?

Comment: It is indeed installed, I can paste you the command line output when I get access to my computer.